# If $\|Ax\|\equiv\|x\|$, then $(Ax)\cdot(Ay)\equiv x\cdot y$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Let A be a complex square matrix. If $\|Ax\|=\|x\|$ for every vector $x$, then $(Ax)\cdot(Ay)=x\cdot y$ for every pair of vectors $x$ and $y$.

Solution:
$$\operatorname{Re}(x\cdot y)=\frac12(\|x+y\|^2 - \|x\|^2 - \|y\|^2).$$
Hence
$$\operatorname{Re}\left((Ax)\cdot(Ay)\right)=\operatorname{Re}(x\cdot y).$$
But I can't do anything about the imaginary parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Note that $\def\Im{\mathop{\rm Im}}\def\Re{\mathop{\rm Re}}$
$$ \Im(X\cdot Y) = -\Re(iX \cdot Y) $$
Now use what you have proved on $iX$ and $Y$.